# What is relation connecting $H$ (generating matrix of a continuous time random walk) and the laplacian matrix of the graph?

Tags: quantum-information, stochastic-processes

In the paper [Unstructured Search by Random and Quantum Walk](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.14533) by TG Wong, the time evolution of the states of continuous time random walk (CTRW) is given as:

$$\vec{p}(t)=\mathrm{e}^{Lt/\vert\vert L\vert\vert}\vec{p}(0)$$

Here $\vec{p}(0)$ is the state of the system at time 0, $L$ is the Laplacian of the graph and $\vert\vert L\vert\vert# is the spectral norm (the magnitude of the largest eigenvalue of L).
In the book [Quantum Walks and Search Algorithms](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6336-8) by Renato Portugal, the same equation is given as:
$$\vec{p}(t)=M(t) \vec{p}(0)$$

where $M(t)$ is given as,
$$M(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-Ht}$$
and $H$ is defined as:
$$H_{ij}=\begin{cases} d_j\gamma & \text{if }i=j \\ -\gamma & \text{if }i \neq j\text{ and adjacent} \\ 0 & \text{if }i\neq j\text{ and non-adjacent}\end{cases}$$

Comparing both the equations we get

$$H=\frac{-L}{||L||}$$

From the definition of the laplacian operator $L=A-D$
where $A$ is the adjacent matrix defined as:

$A_{ij}=1$ if $j$ has $i$ as a neighbour and $A_{ij}=0$ in all other cases.

And $D$ is a diagonal matrix with $D_{ii}=\operatorname{degree}(i)$
comparing the definitions of $H$ and $L$, we can see that

$$H=-\gamma L$$

But then $\vert\vert L\vert\vert=1/\gamma$

But $L$ is uniquely defined for a graph and one can set different transition rate $(\gamma)$ for the same graph.Then how can there be a link between the maximum of the eigenvalue of $L$ and $\gamma$. What is wrong with my understanding? Or have I made any mistake anywhere?